# How can I check the number of calls to the database in LINQ query when using .NET Core and Code First?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I wrote the following code for one of my controller actions in an ASP.NET Core application and I want to know how many times the database was called. There are two LINQ statements, one that fetches the data and another that sorts the children. How does one confirm the number of database calls? I'm using the localdb that gets created by default in a Code First .NET Core application.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var giftCard = await _context.GiftCards.Include(g=>g.Transactions).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);                   
        if (giftCard == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        giftCard.Transactions = giftCard.Transactions.OrderBy(t => t.TransactionDate).ToList();
        return View(giftCard);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq allows developers to build a query, which is executed once the full query is built. You can build a query using multiple expressions without making a single call to the database. Linq will delay the call until the last possible moment.

In your case, the statement `if (giftCard == null)` explicitly asks for the object. Therefore, a database call will be made to fetch the requested `GiftCard`. Secondly, The `OrderBy` operation will be performed on the transactions that are already in memory (due to `Include(g=>g.Transactions)`). So, no database calls here.

Ultimately, your whole code will make only a single database call.

Comment: I managed to figure it out how to check with SQL Profiler and you are right. Only one call is made with my code above.